# Visual C++ assert breaks at return location

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Something incredibly convenient happens when running this code in debug mode:

```
std::array<int, 2> test;
test[5] = 123;
```

When I hit the "Retry" button on the assert message box, Visual Studio 2015 will show the `test[5] = 123;` line. And I have no idea why it is not breaking at the assert location inside the operator instead.

Does anybody have an explanation for that? Is there a way I can replicate the same behavior in my own code?

edit:

To make it clear, the Visual Studio STL does bounds checking for `operator[]` in Debug mode (_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL), and I am running in Debug mode. The question here is why it breaks at this location and not inside the operator where the assert is actually triggered.

Also notice that with Visual Studio 2013 it breaks inside the operator, so there is a difference in behavior between 2015 and 2013, the plot thickens.

Comment: Which version of Visual Studio and which compiler and linker settings, precisely? I cannot reproduce the behaviour. When I do what you suggest, I get into `stddthrow.cpp`, line 15, `::_CrtDbgBreak();`. The next item in the call stack is in file `array`, line 149, inside of `operator[]`.

Comment: Look at the call stack... it probably did break at the assert call, but placed the debugger focus on a different frame in the call stack.  Options such as Tools->Options->Debugger->Enable "Just My Code" affect this focus.

Comment: @BenVoigt: I think that option is only relevant for the "step into" action. It does not seem to affect the debugger focus when a `CrtDbgBreak()` is hit, at least not with Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: Good remark @ChristianHackl, the behavior is different with VS 2013, with this version it breaks inside the operator.

Comment: @Drealmer: Perhaps the question is whether this is a bug or a feature... :)

Comment: @ChristianHackl: I think "Just My Code" is implemented using a blacklist.... possibly `CrtDebugBreak()` has been added to the list since.

Comment: @BenVoigt yes I suspect some kind of blacklist somewhere, but I have no idea where nor if I can affect it somehow

Comment: I am leaning towards "bug". https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn457346.aspx says: *"When the debugger hits an exception, it will stop on the exception regardless of whether it is in user or non-user code."*

Comment: @Christian: According to the docs (which we both found), it affects both stepping and call stack, but they are treated differently, with separate rules and configuration.

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you all! Now if only I could control that with a #pragma it would be the best thing ever since sliced bread.

Comment: @Drealmer: Hmmm... do you really think it's a good idea to have the code itself dictate how it will be debugged?

Comment: @ChristianHackl in a way, a debug break is already having the code itself dictating how to debug it, and I would find it less confusing to have a pragma next to the ignored code rather than controlling this behavior from within some external preferences file. Probably less clean, but more convenient imho.

Answer (score 3):

For Visual Studio 2015, the process by which the debugger determines which functions are not "My Code" and customization is documented:

- [C++ Just My Code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn457346.aspx#BKMK_C___Just_My_Code)

> You can specify modules, source files, and functions to treat as non-user code in call stacks by specifying them in `*.natjmc` files.